# Apple Pay Payment certificate is not trusted

Tags: ios, certificate, applepay

I am working on implementing Apple Pay in my ios app, For that I tried to create certificates on the apple account.

I followed this [setting_up_apple_pay_requirements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/apple_pay/setting_up_apple_pay_requirements) link.

and followed the exectly these three steps

1.) Create a merchant ID.

2.)Create a Payment Processing certificate.

3.) Enable Apple Pay in Xcode.

But in my key chain when i added the created certificate, then it is showing **"Apple Pay Payment Processing:"merchent id" certificate is not trusted"**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I followed this [trust error in key cain certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/ApplePay_Guide/Configuration.html)

where it says "**If you see a warning in Keychain Access that the certificate was signed by an unknown authority or that it has an invalid issuer, make sure you have the WWDR intermediate certificate - G2 and the Apple Root CA - G2 installed in your keychain. You can download them from apple.com/certificateauthority.**"

After downloading and adding "**Worldwide Developer Relations - G2 Certificate**
" certificates into key chain. Now its is saying "**This certificate is valid**"

[Download certificate from here](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/)

Comment: solved my problem certificate was not trusted but i downloaded g2 and its now trusted

Comment: Is this certificate exported from keychain to provide to payment gateway ? @Parv Bhasker